# How to formulate this question involving logical equivalence?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4586344/is-p-rightarrow-q-rightarrowr-rightarrow-s-logically-equivalent-to-p-rig) is puzzling me. It is as follows:

Is (p→q)→(r→s) logically equivalent to (p→r)→(q→s)?

If we then write this as a biconditional:

[(p→q)→(r→s)] <--> [(p→r)→(q→s)]

We can find that when using a truth table, the biconditional is not always true. So this would seem to give an answer of "no" to the OP's question.

But the part that's puzzling me - what if we negate this biconditional? E.g.,

![(p→q)→(r→s)] <--> [(p→r)→(q→s)]

When plugging this into a truth table, there are also some cases where it is false. So does this imply the answer to the OP's question isn't "no"?

I have a few theories:

- One suspicion of mine is that "logically equivalent" in this context cannot be interpreted as a biconditional in the way I have done, but I can't figure out why doing this is a problem.
- The other theory I have is that the answer to the OP's question is neither yes or no. This is something I mentioned at the end of [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4586344/is-p-rightarrow-q-rightarrowr-rightarrow-s-logically-equivalent-to-p-rig/4586537#4586537) to that question.

Comment: They are equivalent if the biconditional works all the time.  They are not equivalent if the biconditional fails some of the time.  To be not equivalent does not require that the biconditional fail all the time.  The answer to the original question is NO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two statements being equivalent means that they *always* have the same truth-value, no matter what.  So, if they are not equivalent, then that could be because they sometimes have the same truth-value, and sometimes they don't.  Please note that in such case you do *not* (contrary to your suggestion in 2.) want to say that they are sometimes equivalent, and sometimes not. No!! Sometimes having the same truth-value and sometimes not having the same truth-value means that they do *no* *always* have the same truth-value, and hence they are  *not* equivalent, period.

Also, if you now negate the biconditional ... or negate one of the sides (as you do), then in the truth-table all values get flipped: where the original biconditional was true, the new statement will be false, and vice versa. So, since the original biconditional was sometimes true and sometimes false, that means that the new statements will *also* be sometimes true and sometimes false ... and therefore *also* *not* indicate an equivalence.

Here is a simpler scenario. Take two completely unrelated statementas $P$ and $Q$.  Are they logically equivalent?  Clearly not!  And indeed, if you work out $P \leftrightarrow Q$ in a truth-table, you will find that it is not always true (though sometimes it is). OK, so let's now consider $\neg P \leftrightarrow Q$.  Well, that statement also is sometimes true and sometimes false (again, its values are just flipped from $P \leftrightarrow Q$. So this biconditional is also not *always* true, and therefore also *not* indicative of any equivalence.  OK, but does that means that now suddenly $P \leftrightarrow Q$ *is* always true, i.e. that $P$ and $Q$ *are* equivaklent?  Clearly not.  All you have found is that $P$ and $Q$ are not equivalent, nor equivalent to any negation thereof. They are just two completely independent statements!

Comment: So would a proper translation of the OP's problem (in that other question) be: "Is [(p→q)→(r→s)] <--> [(p→r)→(q→s)] a tautology?"

Comment: @InertialIgnorance Yes! Two statements are equivalent if and only if the biconditional between them is a tautology.

Answer (score 0):

Note that we state that two well-formed formulas $\alpha$, $\beta$ are equivalent if $\alpha \vdash \beta$ and $\beta \vdash \alpha$.

Moreover, we can ensure that $\vdash \alpha \leftrightarrow \beta$ implies that $v[\alpha]=v[\beta]$ for any valuation of $\alpha, \beta$, the latter can be easily verified using Soundness Theorem.

Now, the valuations can be seen represented as the truth values in the table you mention. Note also that by Soundness Theorem if $(p→q)→(r→s)$ is equivalent to $(p→r)→(q→s)$ then $\vdash (p→q)→(r→s) \leftrightarrow (p→r)→(q→s)$ i.e. $\models (p→q)→(r→s) \leftrightarrow (p→r)→(q→s)$ but the latter implies that $v[(p→q)→(r→s)]=v[(p→r)→(q→s)]=V$

But if you look at the truth table, every well-formed formula has some values at which it becomes false, so the above could not happen. Thus the well-formed formulas you indicate are not equivalent.